# PHP, Curl Get Variable and Response

Tags: php, variables, curl, get, icecast

I have a form...

```
<form action="response.php" method="get" name="titles">
<p><input id="titles" onclick="this.select()" type="text" name="titles" value="Live Now! DJ Name - Show Name" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Delivering a variable $titles to response.html. However it's not working correctly.

The format of my response.php output should be...

```
http://adminusername:adminpassword@mysite.com:8000/admin/metadata?mount=/mountname&mode=updinfo&song=$myvariableforminputhere
```

Here is response.html The form seems to work, but I have something wrong with including my variable. I'm a bit of a hack sorry, and have borrowed bits of other peoples code:/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Form Variables Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
{
//simply copy and paste this code block for each server you need to add
$serv["host"][] = "mysite.com"; //ip or hostname the server is running on. Don't include http://
$serv["port"][] = "8000"; //port the server is running on
$serv["mount"][] = "/mymount"; //this format: /mount
$serv["user"][] = "user"; //icecast server username
$serv["passwd"][] = "pass"; //icecast server password
echo $_GET["titles"];

    {
        $mysession = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$serv["host"][$count].":".$serv["port"][$count]."/admin/metadata?mount=".$serv["mount"][$count]."&mode=updinfo&song=test".$titles);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $serv["user"][$count].":".$serv["passwd"][$count]);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_exec($mysession);
        curl_close($mysession);
    }

    echo "song updated";
}
?>

<p><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Thanks to User: byf-ferdy the below response.php now works with my form code above. Thanks also to Audioprobe at http://forum.loudcity.net/viewtopic.php?id=4160 for the original code!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//Set up java for back button
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

//simply copy and paste this code block for each server you need to add
$serv["host"][] = "mysite.com"; //ip or hostname the server is running on. Don't include http://
$serv["port"][] = "8000"; //port the server is running on
$serv["mount"][] = "/mymount"; //this format: /mount
$serv["user"][] = "user"; //icecast server username
$serv["passwd"][] = "pass"; //icecast server password

$encoded = urlencode($_GET['titles']); //Make sure '+' and spaces are sent correctly by encoding all +'s to be %2B

        $mysession = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$serv["host"].":".$serv["port"]."/admin/metadata?mount=".$serv["mount"]."&mode=updinfo&song=".$encoded);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $serv["user"].":".$serv["passwd"]);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
        curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_exec($mysession);
        curl_close($mysession);

    echo "Titles updated: ";
    echo $_GET["titles"];

?>
<!--Implement back button-->
<p><input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you removed certain conditions or loops? or why do you have `{` and `}` in your code? It is usually used with e.g. an `if` statement: `if (condition) { }`. Also can you describe **"The form seems to work, but I have something wrong with including my variable.** this? What does not work? Do you get any error messages? What happens if you use `var_dump($_GET['titles'])` instead of `echo $_GET['titles']`?

Comment: The form seems to work, but I have something wrong with including my variable. This means my HTML Form code seems to result in the desired passing of my variable to response.php `http://www.mysite.com/filelocation/response.php?titles=myvariable`. I'll get back to you about the other questions.

Comment: I have removed an if statement. Should I remove all curly brackets?

Comment: Adding `var_dump($_GET['titles'])` results in an output of... `string(10) "myvariable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already wrote in my comments you should remove the curly brackets since they are obsolete in your code. Also remove in all the lines

```
$serv["host"][] = "budgiecollective.dyndns.org";
```

the `[]` so the line just looks like this:

```
$serv["host"] = "budgiecollective.dyndns.org";
```

Afterwards remove any occurance of `[$count]` in your code since the variable is not used anymore.
Last but not least change the `$titles` to `$_GET['titles']` in this line:

```
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$serv["host"][$count].":".$serv["port"][$count]."/admin/metadata?mount=".$serv["mount"][$count]."&mode=updinfo&song=test".$titles);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I have made the updates and think I am very close.

Maybe if I add in a print/write line to display the server's xml response I might be able to read what the error is.

The response I expect is...

Comment: `<iceresponse>
  <message>Metadata update successful</message>
  <return>1</return>
</iceresponse>`

Comment: the response body of you request can be accessed via `$content = curl_exec($mysession)`

Comment: `$content = curl_exec($mysession);` Produces the error `Warning: curl_exec(): 1 is not a valid cURL handle resource`

Comment: The curl_exec didn't work. But it's working.. thanks! I'll post my new code to help future peoples. Ultimately I'd like to parse the xml response message to offer users of the Form some meaningful feedback. But at least I works!

Comment: Have a look at the [SimpleXMLElement Class](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)